# Random function

Tags: randomness, function

Is this function safe?
I want to generate a random number without any external input.

```
abstract contract F {
    //current block time when the contract was created
    uint256 private currentTime=block.timestamp; // this will neved be edited
    function random2() public returns (uint) {
        return currentTime % block.number / 10;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Solidity implements `block.prevrandao`, you can use the old name `block.difficulty`. This gets a randomness beacon from the beacon chain.

Sources

- https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4399
- https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/13512